# Input validation using pattern attribute in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i am new to reactjs. I want to validate the input element with pattern attribute (can accept atleast one character) in reactjs. Below is what i have tried doing.

```
handle_text_input_change = (event) => {
    this.props.onChange(event);
    console.log("handle",event.target.name);
    this.setState({text_input_value: event.target.value});
    this.validate(event);
};

validate = (event) => {
    let name = event.target.name;
    console.log("target name", name);
    //const target = event.target;
    if (event.target.ValidityState.patternMismatch) {
            this.setState({is_valid: false});
            this.setState({error: 'Enter the'+ {name} +'with atleast one 
         character'});
     }};

 return (
        <div>
            <input {...rest}
                type="text"
                onChange={this.handle_text_input_change}
                disabled={disabled}
                onBlur={this.handle_blur}
                onFocus={this.handle_focus}
                pattern=".+"
            />
            {(valid && active)&& <span className="error">Enter a name</span>}
        </div>
    );
```

So this will display the error message when input invalid. However, in the validate method i am checking if input value not null then consider valid. But how can i do input validation using pattern attribute and display error message similarly. Thanks.

Edited: I have tried using html5 validation api as in above code. but then i get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueMissing' of undefined". could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added a `value` property on your `input`:

```
<input {...rest}
  type="text"
  onChange={this.handle_text_input_change}
  disabled={disabled}
  onBlur={this.handle_blur}
  onFocus={this.handle_focus}
  value={this.state.text_input_value}
/>
```

Comment: i meant how to use pattern attribute for input element like so <input pattern=".+"/> and use that pattern to validate using html5 validation api...ok will edit my question again. thanks.